# Changing vmax in js

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I want to change the size of a div when the ''grid'' is changed (for example - for 10x10 grid I want my divs to be 3vmax, for 11x11 I want my divs to be 2.9vmax and so on....)
I tried to do sth like that but it doesn't quite work the way I want:( Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/diana-larussa/pen/OJRZMXp

```
function newGrid() {

    while (container.firstChild) {
        container.removeChild(container.firstChild)
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < gridDOMElement.value*gridDOMElement.value; index++) {
        const div = document.createElement("div")
        container.appendChild(div)
    }

    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat("+gridDOMElement.value+", `${3 - gridDOMElement.value * 0.1}vmax`)"
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = "repeat("+gridDOMElement.value+", `${3 - gridDOMElement.value * 0.1}vmax`)"

    let divElement = document.querySelectorAll('div')

    for (let i = 0; i < gridDOMElement.value*gridDOMElement.value; ++i) {
        divElement[i].style.height = `${3 - gridDOMElement.value * 0.1}vmax`
        divElement[i].style.width = `${3 - gridDOMElement.value * 0.1}vmax`
    }
    
}
```

Comment: here's a fix for your vmax calculation. you don't need to do it every loop either, just do it before the loop like `const vmax = 3 - ( (~~gridDOMElement.value - 10) * .1)` then reference vmax where needed (including outside of the loop when assigning the template columns to the container if desired). let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I'm not sure how to reference it, can you help me please?
 `const vmax = 3 - ( (~~gridDOMElement.value - 10) * .1)
        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat("+gridDOMElement.value+", 3"+vmax+")"
        container.style.gridTemplateRows = "repeat("+gridDOMElement.value+", 3"+vmax+")"

        let divElement = document.querySelectorAll('div')
        for (let i = 0; i < gridDOMElement.value*gridDOMElement.value; ++i) {
            divElement[i].style.height = "3"+vmax+""
            divElement[i].style.width = "3"+vmax+""
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
function newGrid() {

    while (container.firstChild) {
        container.removeChild(container.firstChild)
    }

        for (let index = 0; index < gridDOMElement.value*gridDOMElement.value; index++) {
            const div = document.createElement("div")
            container.appendChild(div)
        }

        const vmax = 3 - ( (~~gridDOMElement.value - 10) * .1)
        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat("+gridDOMElement.value+", "+vmax+"vmax)"
        container.style.gridTemplateRows = "repeat("+gridDOMElement.value+", "+vmax+"vmax)"

        let divElement = document.querySelectorAll('div')
        for (let i = 0; i < gridDOMElement.value*gridDOMElement.value; ++i) {
            divElement[i].style.height = ""+vmax+"vmax"
            divElement[i].style.width = ""+vmax+"vmax"
        }
}
```